# Почему код не работает? Что с переменной f?

Tags: python

```
def a(x):
    i = 0
    while (10**i-1)%x != 0:
        i=i+1
        if i>100:
            return 0
    return i

f=3
while f < 100:
    print(a(f))
    f = f+1
```

Этот код должен писать остатки деления на сто. Но она выводит одни нули. Почему?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: все с ней отлично, не переживайте. вы никогда не попадаете в ваш while

Comment: а что с ней? а что этот код должен делать? А что он на самом деле делает? Откуда вообще известно, что он не работает?

Comment: А что делает код? Какого поведения вы ожидаете от программы? Вы хоть немного опишите проблему, а то тут вряд ли кто-то хочет быть участником шоу "Интуиция". Так-то код работает и замечательно выводит нули.

Answer (score 1):

Единственная проблема в том, что строка
`while (10**i-1)%x != 0:` проблематичнa. Здесь `i` будет равен 0, и значит 10**i = 1, 1-1 =0 и 0%3 = 0. В строке `i = 0` замените 0 на 1